# pydantic root validators run in order they were order not in order they are listed in class

Tags: pydantic

I make use of numerous root validators and end up re-sorting them within the Model to try to control order of operation. However it appears that pydantic doesn't respect the order they are listed in the class, but rather the order they were first added in.

I am using Python 3.9.16 and Pydantic 1.10.2.

In the example below, I first added the validator `first_validator` and confirmed it ran successfully. Later I added `second_validator` but want it to execute first. However when I test my model it is the error from `first_validator` that is seen.

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):

    @root_validator(pre=False)
    def second_validator(cls, values):
        raise ValueError(f"error from second_validator!")
        return values

    @root_validator(pre=False)
    def first_validator(cls, values):
        raise ValueError(f"error from first_validator!")
        return values
```

Is there a way to work around this so I can force a predictable order of operation against validators?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing because with your example code the validators _are_ called in the order they are defined in the `MyModel` class. Also, it is unclear what exactly you mean by _"the order they were first added in"_ (as opposed to _"the order they are listed in the class"_). Are you referring to **inherited** root validators from a parent class and the fact that those will be called first, even if you override them in a subclass _after_ the definition of a new root validator? If so, please edit your example accordingly to actually demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I will have to dig into it more because the example above is greatly simplified from what I have in production and not completely representative. What I have been seeing is if I add another root validator and place it above an existing one in the model, it is errors from the validator further down (a validator added prior) that is raised, not the one above it.

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation:](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#:%7E:text=where%20validators%20rely,in%20this%20example.)

> where validators rely on other values, you should be aware that:
>
> Validation is done in the order fields are defined. E.g. in the
> example above, password2 has access to password1 (and name), but
> password1 does not have access to password2. See Field Ordering for
> more information on how fields are ordered If validation fails on
> another field (or that field is missing) it will not be included in
> values, hence if 'password1' in values and ... in this example.

You can read more here:

https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#field-ordering

Comment: I think that just refers to field validators though right, and not root validators?

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the late edit, but you can see I fixed the second link, I didn't realise I'd posted the same link twice, but you can see that the docs on field ordering mention that validators are ordered by the order of fields, there's also another blurb in the "Warning" element that mentions you should always include fields and type annotations on them as there are some limitations around how Python can handle the ordering.

Comment: Also, I know this is a flimsy answer, but maybe look at the v2 for Pydantic, there are a tonne of changes coming, to the degree that I am currently working on a project that I'm going to have to change a bunch of stuff on simply because the v2 fixes a bunch of issues that I added work arounds for. Looking at the plan/roadmap doesn't show much for root_validators, in fact, they seem to be becoming more important/more recommended for more solutions, but it wouldn't hurt to look. https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/blog/pydantic-v2-alpha/

Comment: While I also look forward to Pydantic 2, to be fair, neither your post nor your comments provide an answer to the question whatsoever. The question itself is not particularly clear, but it is unambiguously about root validators, not field validators, and nowhere in the documentation you linked does it explain the order that non-`pre=True` root validators are called with respect to one another (only to field validators).